# Angular and DevExtreme

Tags: angularjs, devextreme

Im using Angular Approach for DevExtreme.

I'm just trying to run this code, but so far, I didn't get run.

This is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myCalc">

<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/angular.js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/angular.js/angular-sanitize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/angular.js/angular-resource.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/libs/angular.js/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/globalize/0.1.1/globalize.min.js"></script>


    <script src="js/libs/angular.js/dx.webapp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>            
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/15.1.3/css/dx.common.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/15.1.3/css/dx.light.css" />

    <script src="js/libs/angular.js/dx.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>




</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl" >

    <form>
        <br>
        <br>            
            Parameter 1: 
        <input type="text" ng-model="param1">
        <br>
        <br>
            Parameter 2: 
        <input type="text" ng-model="param2">
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>


 <div dx-button="{
        text: 'Sample GET',
        clickAction: click()
    }"></div>



     <br>
     <div>Sum: {{data}}</div>
     <br>
</body>
```

This is my script:

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('myCalc', [ 'dx' ] )
angular.module('myCalc', ['ngRoute'])


    .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
        $scope.click = function(url) {
          $scope.url = url;

            $http.get($scope.url, {
                params: {
                    param1: $scope.param1,
                    param2: $scope.param2

            },
            cache: $templateCache
        }).
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
        }).
        error(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
        });
      }; 
 })


.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
     .when('http://localhost:8000/calc', {
      templateUrl: 'index.html',
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    });
  // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

})(window.angular);
```

Also, I have a server in NodeJS as:

```
var url = require('url');
//Require express, 
var express = require('express');
//and create an app
var app = express();

//app.get() which represents the HTTP GET method
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

//app.get() which represents the HTTP GET method param1/:param1/param2/:param2
app.get('/calc', function (req, res) {

    url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
    console.log(url);
    console.log(url_parts);
    a = parseInt(url_parts.query.param1);
    console.log(a);
    b = parseInt(url_parts.query.param2);
    console.log(b);

    output = a+b;
    console.log(output);
    res.writeHead(200, {
                   'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'});
    res.end(output + "\n");  
});

var server = app.listen(8000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Example app listening at http://' + host + ':' + port);
});
```

Whats happening that I didnt get run this code?
Can somebody help me?

Thanks
Rodrigo

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myCalc due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module dx due to:
Error: [$compile:baddir] Directive name 'DOMComponent' is invalid. The first character must be a lowercase letter
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$compile/baddir?p0=DOMComponent

Comment: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=dx&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24compile%3Abaddir%5D%20Directive%20name%20'DOMComponent'%20is%20invalid.%20The%20first%20character%20must%20be%20a%20lowercase%20letter%0Ahttp%3A

Comment: %2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0%2F%24compile%2Fbaddir%3Fp0%3DDOMComponent%0A%20%20%20%20at%20REGEX_STRING_REGEXP%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8383%2FHTML5Applica

Comment: tionAngularExpressJS%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2Fangular.js%3A68%3A12)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20assertValidDirectiveName%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8383%2FHTML5ApplicationAngularExpressJS%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2Fangular.js%3A6878%3A13)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20%24CompileProvider.registerDirective%20%5Bas%20directive%5D%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8383%2FHTML5ApplicationAngularExpressJS%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2Fangular.js%3A6905%3A7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20runInvokeQueue%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8383%2FHTML5ApplicationAngularExpressJS%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2Fangular.js%3A4332%3A35)

Comment: There are errors when I run the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your application as described [here](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Demos_Inside/Tip_Calculator_on_AngularJS_Demo/?search=angular&version=15_1&approach=Knockout#Tip_Calculator_on_AngularJS_Demo)

The main difference is use `ng-view` instead `ng-controller` in the `index.html` file. Also, there is small code refactoring.

You can download the simple project here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ayc00jb0gg7xfdl/ng.zip?dl=0 and run it in your local web server.

Hope it helps!

**[Upd]**

This [article](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/UI_Widgets/Basics/Working_with_Widgets/?version=15_1#Add_a_Widget) describes step by step how to use DevExtreme widgets with the AngularJS framework.

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (16:39:17:558 | error, network)
  at http://localhost:8383/AngularApplicationDevExt/[object%20Object]
TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function
    at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:83:467)
    at m (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:82:308)
    at $get.f

Comment: I tried update all the program and found the error above.
How Do I do to pass parameters via DevExtreme like this:
       <div dx-button="{
                            text: 'Sample GET',
                            onClick: click ('write here something?'
                            }">
            </div>

Comment: Can I get some parameter like this in dx-button, event onClick like this:
      <div dx-button="{
                            text: 'Sample GET',
                            onClick: click('http://localhost:8000/calc')
                            }">
            </div>

Comment: `onClick` option should contain function name from controller. See this example http://jsbin.com/bubejipane/edit?html,output Would you please clarify for what reason you want to use approach you described? I mean pass something to onClick handler.

Comment: Sergey, I'm using to do an experimental test to use an architecture with NodeJs, ExpressJS, AngularJS, DevExtreme.